# is it possible to use Ui button to work continous on unity

Tags: unity

i want to use Ui buttons as joyStick arrows to move character. but as i know buttons just work once. not continous. so is it possible to make button work continous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an event trigger with Pointer enter.

Add a Event Trigger component with the UI object. Add input as Pointer Enter. Refer the object as you do with Button object and select the public function on the script.

[image: Sample Event Trigger]

Comment: i think its not a effient way but there is no other way. thanks

Comment: It's efficient. Unity's standard asset Joystick is developed based on these events.

Comment: alright. i just tested it on blueStacks and looks working well.